# Style Icon with fixed size

Tags: openlayers

I try to style a point geometry feature like this, expexting it to have a 14px x 14px size. However, the feature is not displayed at all. When I remove the `size` parameter, the icon is displayed in its original size from server. How do I fix that?

```
   let style = new ol.style.Icon({
            size: [14,14],
            src:  "images/myicon.png",
        })
```

Comment: use the scale option to change size relative to the original size

Comment: The problem is, I may have several icons with different original sizes, but I want them all to be displayed in the same, static size.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the scale after the image has loaded (it might load immediately if in browser cache)

```
let style = new ol.style.Icon({
            src:  "images/myicon.png",
        })

let image = style.getImage();
if (!image.width) {
  image.addEventListener('load', function () {
    style.setScale([14 / image.width, 14 / image.height]);
  });
} else {
  style.setScale([14 / image.width, 14 / image.height]);
}
```

Comment: well, the size parameter exists. There must be a way to make it work / a reason why it does not work the way I expect it.

Comment: `size` specifies how much of the original image to use, not how to scale it